# Ionic 4 app not working in android Lollipop

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-view, ionic4

I created an Ionic 4 android app which is working fine in Android 8. But when I test it in Android 5 (As an app and in the browser both), getting the below error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.       vendor.js:71605
```

Enabled polyfill.ts, but that didn't help.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: There is a bug with Ionic 4. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15438
Not sure why people are down voting.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to compile to ES2015.

Try adding this:

```
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2015"
  }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word vendor.js:140
Uncaught SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode. main.js:104
2 errors are there now!

Comment: Did you try this and build the app again?

Answer (score 0):

if you use require declaration change it to import

import {foo} from 'bar';
Is equivalent to:
var foo = require('bar').foo;